# bright squares showing up when rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I want to render something, but these random squares show up:
[image]

Here are some of my render settings:

[image]

[image]

(If you want to know another setting, just comment and i'll post it)

Thanks
Daniel

EDIT: I fixed it by rendering using CUDA instead of OPTIX and now there’s no random bright squares.

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: Hello :). I remember some issues like this when using tile denoising. Does it happen with denoising disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Light clamping when done incorrectly can be problem sometimes, I have tested different values, and 500 for both Direct Light and Indirect Light worked best.